# Does the summation symbol imply precedence over multiplication?

Tags: notation

Does

$$a\sum_{n=1}^N x_n$$ mean $$a(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ... + x_N)$$ or $$a * x_1 + x_2 + x_3 ... + x_N$$

Edit: So apparently the first option is the correct one, but why? Multiplication has precedence over summation, right?

Comment: It means the former.  Well, it means $a(x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_N)$ (you accidentally typed $n$ instead of $N$).

Comment: The usual elementary school order of operations doesn't really contemplate functions and operators.  If we define $S=b+c$ then $a\times S$ means $a\times (b+c)$, not $a\times b+c$.   For example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a notational convention: things inside a summation ($\Sigma$) or product ($\Pi$) sign are considered to be a single entity for terms of other operations applied to them.  So while multiplication of single elements takes precedence over addition, the summation or product sign binds "more tightly".

So,
$$ax_1 +x_2$$ applies the $a$ only to $x_1$, but
$$a\sum_{i=1}^2 x_i$$ expands out to $ax_1 +ax_2$ always.

When you start dealing with infinite sums and products this is important.  In an infinite-dimensional Banach space the (formal) sum
$$\sum_{j\in {\mathbb N}} \alpha_j x_j$$
may or may not be an element of the space.  (For example, if the Banach space is $c_0$ and each $\alpha_j =1$ and the $\{x_j\}_{j\in {\mathbb N}}$ are the standard basis then the resulting sum is *not* an element of $c_0$ but rather of its bidual, $l_\infty$.)  Multiplying the formal sum by something can affect which space it lives in then, so you need to be accurate in recording what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

You can't get it wrong with a multiplication on the left, the sum is taken as a whole and clearly

$$a\sum b_i=a\left(\sum b_i\right).$$

Malicious guy could tell you that there is ambiguity in

$$\sum a_i\ b$$ which could be interpreted as

$$\left(\sum a_i\right)b$$

or
$$\sum \left(a_i\ b\right)$$

but by the distributivity law, these are equivalent.

Different is

$$\sum a_i+b$$ which could be understood as

$$\left(\sum a_i\right)+b$$ or $$\sum\left(a_i+b\right).$$

Without parenthesis, the first interpretation holds.

Answer (score 1):

It means the former.

Let's think that we have some numbers $x_1, x_2, x_3 \dots x_n$

Now, we multiply each by a constant $a$ and add them. We get : $$ax_1 + ax_2 + \dots ax_n\\ = \sum^n_{i=1}ax_i$$

Using distributive property of addition, we can rewrite this as : $$a(x_1 + x_2 + \dots +x_n)\\= a\sum^n_{i=1}x_i$$

Answer (score 0):

From the definition for the **summation** notation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N x_n = x_1 + x_2 +...+x_{N-1} +x_N$$

Now you multiply $a$ to both sides and apply the distributive property:
$$a\sum_{n=1}^N x_n = a(x_1 + x_2 +...+x_{N-1} +x_N) = ax_1 + ax_2 +...+ax_{N-1} +ax_N$$